# doGet Servlet not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I'm new and self learnt through online courses and have a trouble understanding why my doGet isn't responding to the sent parameter, my code is very basic actually and It's the exact same as the one that in the video, I'm using Eclipse, and here's the code;

```
package com.linkedin.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CatalogServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/CatalogServlet")
public class CatalogServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CatalogServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.service(request, response);
        response.getWriter().append(request.getParameter("name"));
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

and when I go to ** http://localhost:8080/hsports-catalog-servlet/CatalogServlet?name=AnyName **
it gives me out "Not Found"
thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Remove the call to `super.service(request, response)`. That will `doGet` or `doPost` again (depending on the HTTP method), which means you're in a recursive loop that ends with a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: It still gives out the same output "Not Found"

Comment: Do you have the server output from the Console from when it launched? Can you update the source shown here? Which server is it? Are you sure it's the one on port 8080?

Comment: how do you run the servlet? (Which container, which packaging)

Comment: @nitind I'm using WildFly 24, Yes It's on 8080, it seems connected but for some reason it gives out Not found only,

Comment: @cyberbrain Package com.linkedin.servlet

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me: I did not mean the java "package", but do you create a JAR file, a WAR file, an EAR file, how do you tell the Server that he should serve your code? I'm asking because "Not Found" could mean that your server actually does not know about your servlet, you have to "deploy" it.